# Get post by tag

Tags: posts, functions, query-posts

I want to get several post by tag. So I try to use get_posts() function:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => '3',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag' => 'travel'
);

$recent_posts = get_posts($args);?>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get posts by tag?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this section: [Tag parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) in WP Codex, where is explained search by tags.

Your code like right. Try change numberposts to int:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tag' => 'travel'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find it helpful to check out this link about [WP Queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters) to query by tag.

The advantage of using this query is you can create your own [loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), and you can put the posts in whatever arrangement you need.

For example, you can drop the post titles into a list, or you can generate the standard title headings followed by an excerpt or content.

For a list, the code would look something like this:

```php
<ol>
    <?php 
    $args = array(
        'tag' => 'travel', 
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    );

    $recent_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : 
        while ( $recent_posts->have_posts() ) : $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>

        <li><?php the_title(); ?></li>

        <?php
        endwhile; 
    else :
        echo "Nothing";
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ol>
```